# Why does this code snippet output "true" when it should return "false"?

Tags: ruby

```
ALLOWED_TARGETS = ["dresden", "paris", "vienna"]

def missile_launch_allowed(target, secret_key)
  allowed = true
  аllowed = false if secret_key != 1234
  allowed = false unless ALLOWED_TARGETS.include?(target)
  allowed
end

puts(missile_launch_allowed("dresden", 9999))
```

Found this code snippet in a blog. Tracking the code by hand gives me `false`, but why does this output true when run?

The part I am not seeing is just not crossing my mind at the moment. Please help me understand Ruby a bit better.

Comment: _"Found this code snippet in a blog"_ – in the blog post, was the bug introduced deliberately as a way to circumvent the secret key check? :-)

Comment: [Here's](https://tech.showmax.com/2019/10/how-ruby-can-surprise-you/) the blog post

Comment: @Viktor thanks for the link. Seems like the OP missed the explanation below the code.

Comment: "was the bug introduced deliberately as a way to circumvent the secret key check?" Interesting idea though

Comment: @Stefan yes, I got intrigued and tried before reading the part where this was explained. Actually, good that I didn't read that in full. Got to learn a few things here in the answer and the links that you posted. Also, realizing that "The warnings come after the spells" :)

Comment: FWIW the four lines in the method can be replaced by `secret_key == 1234 && ALLOWED_TARGETS.include?(target)`

Comment: Considering the potential consequences, I'd suggest a key with at least five digits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`allowed` is not `аllowed`; you have two different variables. Specifically, the first letter is different: the first variable has 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A' (U+0061), the second has 'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A' (U+0430). The glyphs are either similar or identical in most (all?) fonts. Your code is thus equivalent to:

```
ALLOWED_TARGETS = ["dresden", "paris", "vienna"]

def missile_launch_allowed(target, secret_key)
  first = true
  second = false if secret_key != 1234
  first = false unless ALLOWED_TARGETS.include?(target)
  first
end

puts(missile_launch_allowed("dresden", 9999))
```

With variables renamed somewhat more sensibly, it should be obvious why you are getting the result you are.

Comment: Ah, I hate these problems :)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks. Pity the people who get asked these kinda questions in interviews :)

Comment: On one hand, I want to strangle people who pose trick questions in interviews. On the other hand, I remember helping a fellow student (years ago, in FORTRAN) find the cause of a segfault they couldn't find for an hour; it was something like `X = A[O]` (where `A[0]` was intended). Glyph equivalence is more of a potential problem today than in ASCII (though I'd say not in actual practice), you can still see it in the wild, and should know to debug it.

Comment: The proper term seems to be [homoglyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph)

Comment: @Stefan Never heard the term, but makes a ton of sense (by analogy).

Comment: @Amadan agree that would be a great story to share among developer friends after figuring out in code. But, I find it not amusing when posed in an interview. What exactly are you testing with such questions in a programming language interview?

Comment: @SyedAslam _"What exactly are you testing with such questions in a programming language interview?"_ – how you approach debugging a strange problem maybe? Or to see if you can think "outside the box".